# Chapters are nesting (appears as sections) within references in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, chapters, koma-script

The title says it all.

Im a little confused on why this is happening and im blind to whats wrong.
(dont mind the second appendix B, i've changed that to C)
However, the appendix A is a subfile.tex with chapter*.

[image: The appendix are un-numbered chapters*]

This is document.tex (main)

```
\providecommand{\main}{.}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed for older TeX distributions
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
  \clearpairofpagestyles 
   \ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark} % \ofoot = outer footer, change to \ifoot for 
    inner footer \cfoot for center footer
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % Fill dots also 
     for chapter leaders
     \renewcommand{\cftdot}{.} % Define the symbol used for dots; can use - 
     or asterisk* or @
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Content} 

\usepackage{subfiles} % For using 'standalone' or individual files, so each 
 can be compiled and seen individually.
    \newcommand{\onlyinsubfile}[1]{#1}
    \newcommand{\notinsubfile}[1]{}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind} % add list of tables, list of figures 
 and bibliography to TOC (numbered)

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{./library}
\cleardoublepage

\subfile{\main/app/app1}\label{sec:app1} % Appendix A 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Appendix A}

\end{document}
```

This is app1.tex:

```
\providecommand{\main}{..}
\documentclass[\main/document.tex]{subfiles}


\begin{document}

\onlyinsubfile
\notinsubfile

\chapter*{\center{ {\large Appendix} {\Huge I}}}
\cleardoublepage

%------------------------------------------
\section{Stereotaxic surgery, drug delivery and head holder implantation}



\end{document}
```

Let me know if you need more from the main.tex
however its very very looong

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working example?

Comment: It has been done @Johannes_B

Comment: Your \addcontentsline command is at the wrong place. Better use commands like \addchap provided by KOMA. Don't use \center inside a chapter command and better don't use tocloft and tocbibind together with a KOMA-class, KOMA has its own tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the `\addcontentsline` is placed after the subfile with the contents of the appendix chapter. So it appears below its section entries with a wrong page number.
Because of `\numberline{}` the entry is indented in TOC. Last but not least `\chapter*` does not change the chapter number. So the section numbers still contain the last chapter number, in your example the chapter number of the bibliography.

You should remove package `tocbibind` and set class options `listof=totoc`, `bibliography=numbered` and maybe `index=totoc`.

Do not use package `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class. With KOMA-Script class option `toc=chapterentrywithdots` you will get dots for the chapter entries.

The title of the TOC can be changed by `\renewcaptionname{english}{\contentsname}{Table of Content}`.

Here is also one possible suggestion for your appendix chapters:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  %a4paper,% default
  toc=chapterentrywithdots,% dots between the chapter entry and its page number in TOC
  listof=totoc,% TOC entries for LOF, LOT etc.
  index=totoc,% TOC entry for index
  bibliography=numbered,% numbered with entry in TOC
  numbers=noenddot% no dot at the end of sectioning numbers etc.
]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
  \clearpairofpagestyles 
   \ofoot*{\pagemark} % short version of \ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\renewcaptionname{english}{\contentsname}{Table of Content}% change the TOC title

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=part,
  level=\chapternumdepth,
  tocstyle=chapter,
  tocindent=0pt,
  tocnumwidth=1.5em,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocentryformat=\usekomafont{chapterentry},
  tocentrynumberformat=\appendixname~
]{appchap}
\makeatletter
\let\c@appchap\c@chapter% use the same counter for both chapter and appchap
\def\theappchap{\thechapter}
\def\cl@appchap{\cl@chapter}% use the same reset list
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\appchapformat}{{\large\appendixname}~\theappchap}
\newcommand*\appendixchapter{\appchap{\mbox{}}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text in the MWE
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\appendix
\appendixchapter
\section{Stereotaxic surgery, drug delivery and head holder implantation}
\Blindtext[2]
\section{Next Section}
\Blindtext
\appendixchapter
\section{Section in the second appendix chapter}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: appendix chapters in TOC]

[image: appendix pages]

---

With package `subfiles` you have to ensure that command `\appendix` is excuted only once! Therefore you can use the `\onlyinsubfile` trick.

Example:

File `document.tex`:

```
\providecommand\main{.}
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  toc=chapterentrywithdots,
  listof=totoc,
  index=totoc,
  bibliography=numbered,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed for older TeX distributions
\usepackage{subfiles}
\newcommand{\onlyinsubfile}[1]{#1}% <- added
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
  \clearpairofpagestyles
  \ofoot*{\pagemark}

\renewcaptionname{english}{\contentsname}{Table of Content}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=part,
  level=\chapternumdepth,
  tocstyle=chapter,
  tocindent=0pt,
  tocnumwidth=1.5em,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocentryformat=\usekomafont{chapterentry},
  tocentrynumberformat=\appendixname~
]{appchap}
\makeatletter
\let\c@appchap\c@chapter
\def\theappchap{\thechapter}
\def\cl@appchap{\cl@chapter}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\appchapformat}{{\large\appendixname}~\theappchap}
\newcommand*\appendixchapter{\appchap{\mbox{}}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\onlyinsubfile[1]{}% <- added
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\appendix
\subfile{\main/app/app1}
\subfile{\main/app/app2}
\end{document}
```

File `app1.tex` in folder `app`:

```
\providecommand\main{..}
\documentclass[\main/document.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\onlyinsubfile{\appendix}% <- ensures that this does not go to the main file
\appendixchapter
\section{Stereotaxic surgery, drug delivery and head holder implantation}
\Blindtext[2]
\section{Next Section}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

File `app2.tex` in folder `app`:

```
\providecommand\main{..}
\documentclass[\main/document.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\onlyinsubfile{\appendix}% <- ensures that this does not go to the main file
\appendixchapter
\section{Section in the second appendix chapter}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

The result of the main file `document.tex` is the same as above.

Comment: I know this is stupid, but how do you change the name of the Appendix using your given code, right now both are named appendix A in the TOC..

Comment: bear in mind im using subfiles.. So writing \appendix \appendixchapter is written in the seperate subfile. I guess that confuses the counter

Comment: You have to ensure that `\appendix` is used only once. See my updated answer.